# Force Google Drive to stay on the old version

Tags: windows-7, chrome, google-drive

Each time I log in to Google Drive, it loads the new Google Drive UI. I switch to the old version, and then the next time it loads the new Google Drive again.

I am looking for a program (Windows 7), Google Chrome extension or script that can force Google Drive to stay on the old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a shortcut, batch file or bookmark to [here](https://drive.google.com/?srtp=0&authuser=0#my-drive):

```
https://drive.google.com/?srtp=0&authuser=0#my-drive
```

and use that to log on to drive